# Job Scheduling for java apps

Tags: java, shell, scheduled-tasks

I am planing to use scheduling for some of my system to periodically do things related to my java based application what will the ideal solution for this

1) create Rest services and call them with curl 
2) use java spring scheduling or quarts 
3) separate out the logic entirely from my app and do it all in scripts (shell etc)

Comment: This is very subjective but generally it can be better to schedule from the outside, given that schedule settings might often need to be re-configured. Otherwise if the scheduling is hard coded into the app, to change it you'll need to edit properties file and restart - or in worst case recompile and redeploy your app...

Comment: have u checked the good old "cron"?